# Opencv: How to detect pixel color change

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, numpy

I have succeeded to colorize the area I want of a given picture created using

```
numpy (`img = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)`).
```

I display the picture using OpenCV

```
cv2.imshow()
```

After colorization using the mouse cursor, I save the picture.

How can I detect that the color of a given pixel of my image has been modified?

Comment: Compare it to a stored version of the initial array/pixel?

Comment: @OliverW. I think what you say is one of the solutions: save the original matrix and compared it to the new one, pixel by pixel. I do not know if `numpy` could help to accelerate such comparaison. Thank you

Comment: There are so many questions and answers on stackoverflow dealing with "[comparing two numpy arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[python]+compare+two+numpy+arrays)". Have you had a look on how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, comparing two arrays can be done with the usual `==`, `<`, `!=`, etc operators.  The comparison returns a boolean (True/False) array:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
y = np.array([9, 1, 2, 3, 7])

arrays_equal = x == y
```

`arrays_equal` will be a boolean array, `True`where they're equal and `False` where they're not:

```
array([False,  True,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

---

However, there's an additional caveat because you're working with image data.  What you probably want to get in the end is a *2D array* of where any color has changed, but you're comparing two *3D arrays*, so you'll get a 3D boolean array as output.

For example:

```
im = np.zeros((5,5,3), dtype=np.uint8)
im2 = im.copy()

# Change a pixel in the blue band:
im2[0,0,2] = 255

# The transpose here is just so that the bands are printed individually 
print (im == im2).T
```

This will yield:

```
[[[ True  True  True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True  True  True]]

 [[ True  True  True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True  True  True]]

 [[False  True  True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True  True  True]]]
```

Of course, what you probably wanted was something more like the last band.

In this case, you want to use `np.all` to "reduce" things down and get a 2D array of where *any color in any pixel* is different.

To do this, we'll use the `axis` kwarg to `np.all` to specify that the comparison should be done along the last axis (`-1` or `2` are equivalent in this case: `-1` just means "last"):

```
np.all(im == im2, axis=-1)
```

Which yields:

```
array([[False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Also note that if you needed to "flip" this array, you could either use the `!=` operator with `np.any` instead of `np.all` or you can invert the result using the `~` (logical not in numpy) operator. E.g. `opposite = ~boolean_array`.

Comment: Full  and perfect explanation. Thank you very much.